# Increasing a VM's CPUs beyond the host's CPU count

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, hyper-v

I recently noted a Hyper-V VM with consistently high CPU usage. It's a terminal server with several people logged in concurrently, all running several apps each. I increased the VM core count, and this did help, as expected.

However, when overall CPU usage runs above 90% for this VM, usage on the host server running Hyper-V doesn't exceed 20%. And that's while running a few other VMs.

The physical server has six cores with hyperthreading enabled. VM cores don't seem to correlate to actual physical cores on the host as far as I can tell. So if the host has a lot more CPU power left, can/should I continue adding more cores to the VM, even exceeding the physical core count?

The host has six cores with hyperthreading enabled. Is setting this VM to have 12 cores optimal? How can I best understand the optimal strategy here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With hyperthreading enabled, your host has 12 logical cores. Resources allocation is dynamic, so your other VMs can still use available CPU resources on your host, while your terminal server is having 12 CPUs allocated, however, I would not do it. You can alternatively, reserve let's say 6 CPUs for your terminal server and see if it helps. Check for some additional information: https://www.hyper-v.io/several-tips-hints-full-throttle-hyper-v-performance/